# Unity .dae importing animations incorrectly

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

I have been having issues importing .dae files exported by Maya into Unity3D.

The animation has a few keyframes (around 20), which can be seen in the .dae snippet bellow

```
<animation>
    <source id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-inputY">
      <float_array id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-inputY-array" count="13">

0.000000 0.066667 9.933333 10.000000 19.966667 24.433333 28.766667 28.833333 33.200000 36.433333 40.500000 43.900000 53.333333</float_array>
      <technique_common>
        <accessor source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-inputY-array" count="13">
          <param name="TIME" type="float"/>
        </accessor>
      </technique_common>
    </source>
    <source id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outputY">
      <float_array id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outputY-array" count="13">

1.602632 1.602632 0.183871 0.183871 -0.009894 -0.009894 0.541865 0.541865 -0.057921 -0.321000 -0.459515 -0.211902 1.602632</float_array>
      <technique_common>
        <accessor source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outputY-array" count="13">
          <param name="Y" type="float"/>
        </accessor>
      </technique_common>
    </source>
    <source id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-intanY">
      <float_array id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-intanY-array" count="13">

0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.244109 -0.038415 -0.039776 0.227513 0.000000</float_array>
      <technique_common>
        <accessor source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-intanY-array" count="13">
          <param name="Y" type="float"/>
        </accessor>
      </technique_common>
    </source>
    <source id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outtanY">
      <float_array id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outtanY-array" count="13">

0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.180752 -0.048316 -0.033255 0.631237 0.000000</float_array>
      <technique_common>
        <accessor source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outtanY-array" count="13">
          <param name="Y" type="float"/>
        </accessor>
      </technique_common>
    </source>
    <source id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-interpolationY">
      <Name_array id="Idle_RHD-translate-animation-interpolationY-array" count="13">
BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER BEZIER
BEZIER BEZIER</Name_array>
      <technique_common>
        <accessor source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-interpolationY-array" count="13">
          <param type="name"/>
        </accessor>
      </technique_common>
    </source>
    <sampler id="Idle_RHD-translate-animationY">
      <input semantic="INPUT" source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-inputY"/>
      <input semantic="OUTPUT" source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outputY"/>
      <input semantic="IN_TANGENT" source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-intanY"/>
      <input semantic="OUT_TANGENT" source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-outtanY"/>
      <input semantic="INTERPOLATION" source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animation-interpolationY"/>
    </sampler>
    <channel source="#Idle_RHD-translate-animationY" target="Idle_RHD/translate.Y"/>
 </animation>
```

However, when unity gets a hold of this file, and I view it in the animation window, there is a keyframe on EVERY frame. This is causing issues with the animation.

We cannot use frame reduction, as this actually loses some small details in the animation which are essential.

All we need is for unity to read in the .dae "verbatim", no change at all.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: are you importing as 'legacy' or using Mecanim?

Comment: Usually FBX is a better format for exporting models and animation to Unity.  Autodesk has free plugins for Maya to export in that format.  They even have an application to convert .obj and .dae to .fbx.

Comment: Hi, at current this is unity 3, but we are moving into unity 4. I can explore mecanim and see if that is any better.

Comment: ITo the second comment, I believe we had tried .fbx but had other issues. I can test and see if it fixes the animation though

Answer (score 0):

This is called Baked Animation. Unity needs baked keyframes. Try to uncheck Bake Animation checkbox in FBX export settings. But again, unity will not interpret correctly your animation if the animation curve isn't baked.